# Write postgres query through Active Record query interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following query I run in Postgres:

```
SELECT count(id), to_char(current_sign_in_at, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS sign_in_date
From users
WHERE current_sign_in_at > date '2014-02-16'
GROUP by sign_in_date;
```

When I run this query through ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute I get:

```
[{"count"=>"3", "sign_in_date"=>"2015-02-17"}, {"count"=>"1", "sign_in_date"=>"2014-10-26"}, {"count"=>"1", "sign_in_date"=>"2014-10-18"}]
```

I'm having trouble getting the query to work using the active record query interface though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Rails way :

```
@users = User.group(:sign_in_date)
             .where("current_sign_in_at > date (?)", '2014-02-16')
             .select("count(id) AS count, to_char(current_sign_in_at, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS sign_in_date")
```

Now, iterate through `@users` to get your result as you got by running the *direct* sql as you mentioned in the question.

```
@users.map { |user| {"count"=> user.count, "sign_in_date"=> user.sign_in_date} }
```